# Realtime desktop like web apps

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xmpp, websocket

I am interested in building a realtime desktop like app (something which gmail is good at), So I am interested in knowing what are the options, I am aware of [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and `XMPP` but still what is your suggested option when we have lot of traffic and data to push to client.

Also is Gmail using XMPP for pushing new mails to client?

Comment: Are you looking for client-to-client communication (ex.: Chat, GoogleWave, collaborative document edition, etc.) or server-to-client communication (ex.: Event notification) ?

Comment: Server to client communication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at this blog post : http://blog.superfeedr.com/realtime-web-technologies/ that I wrote a couple weeks ago.

In a nutshell : it really depends on what exatcly is that that you're trying to build. It is also important to understand how "verbose" would be the communications that you mention : 1 message/sec or 1 message/day.

Comment: Great article, Still I have not yet sure of what should I use. I will be having more like 1 message / sec / client

Comment: Then, you definetely need to keep a socket open and make sure you have little overhead in your messages. Socket.io looks like a good solution, but you have to define your own data formats and higher level protocol.